# Operator overloading in pure virtual classes

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, pure-virtual

Hi I'm tring to create something like wrapper class for primitive types but I'm stuck on this issue:

When I try to create interface and be able to use polymorphism with descendants

**edit**

I'm getting

```
function returning abstract class "Var" is not allowed: 
function "Var::operator+" is a pure virtual 
function function "Var::operator-" is a pure virtual function 
function "Var::operator*" is a pure virtual function 
function "Var::operator/" is a pure virtual function
```

Here is my code

```
class Var
{

public:
    Var() {  }
    virtual Var operator+(Var b) = 0;
    virtual Var operator-(Var b) = 0;
    virtual Var operator*(Var b) = 0;
    virtual Var operator/(Var b) = 0;
};

class Decimal : public Var
{

public:
    Decimal(double a) { value = a; }
    Decimal() : Decimal(0) {  };
    virtual Decimal operator+( Decimal b)
    {
        return value + b.value;
    }
    virtual Decimal operator-( Decimal b)
    {
        return value - b.value;
    }
    virtual Decimal operator*( Decimal b)
    {
        return value * b.value;
    }
    virtual Decimal operator/( Decimal b)
    {
        return value / b.value;
    }
    Decimal operator=(double val)
    {
        value = val;
    }

private:
    double value;
};
```

any solution to my problem?

Comment: "tons of errors" offers no help to the people you want to help you.

Comment: In order to override a function of a base class, a member function must match the parameter list exactly and have a covariant return type.

Comment: Also, `value + b.value` etc. produces a `Var`, but your return type (currently) is a `Decimal`, so there would have to be a conversion from `Var` to `Decimal` (but to add one is a rather bad idea).

Comment: The parameter type needs to be the same. Try `const Var&`, otherwise you pass a copy of Var, and Var cannot be instantiated.

Comment: @nikolap As usual you were requested to [**add such information to your question**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24479079/edit). Please do so, in comments it's not really useful (consider like non existent information).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going about this the wrong way. Try a template

```
template<class T>
class Var
{
public:
    typedef T Type;

    Var(const Type& value = Type()) : value(value) {}

    friend Var operator+(const Var& left, const Var& right)
    {
        return Var(left.value + right.value);
    }

private:
    Type value;
};
```